# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' , what do I change?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Where am I going wrong? I'm using Python 3.

```
Error: Top-level exception occurred in callback while processing a message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pollyNode.py", line 394, in callback
    converted_sound = convertAudioToByteArray(("sounds" + device.get_id() + "/speech" + str(count) + ".mp3"))
  File "pollyNode.py", line 274, in convertAudioToByteArray
    image_data = base64.b64encode(audio).decode('utf-8').encode('ascii')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 71, in _wrap_callback_errors
    callback(message)
  File "pollyNode.py", line 415, in callback
    except binascii.Error:
NameError: name 'binascii' is not defined
```

Code:

```
def convertAudioToByteArray(audio):
    image_data = base64.b64encode(audio).decode('utf-8').encode('ascii')
    return image_data

converted_sound = convertAudioToByteArray(("sounds" + device.get_id() + "/speech" + str(count) + ".mp3"))
payload_json = {'type': 'POLRES', 'img_name':data['img_name'], 'audio': converted_sound, 'node_id': device.get_id()}
payload = json.dumps(payload_json)
device_project_id = args.project_id
device_registry_id = args.registry_id
device_id = data['dev_id']
device_region = args.cloud_region
print("Publishing Polly results to device " + data['dev_id'] + "for image " + data['img_name'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode your string `audio` with `.encode("utf8")`:

```
image_data = base64.b64encode(audio.encode("utf8")).decode('utf-8').encode('ascii')
```

Comment: This resolved it but it gave me a new error on the payload line below:

payload_json = {'type': 'POLRES', 'img_name':data['img_name'], 'audio': converted_sound, 'node_id': device.get_id()}
payload = json.dumps(payload_json)

Error: TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable